# Are there 2 tracks running around the world?

Tags: snowpiercer, snowpiercer-2020

Apologies since this is all mostly spoilers. In the new *Snowpiercer* TV show, in the season 1 finale

> a 2nd train appeared running parallel to the Snowpiercer.
>
> This was revealed to be a supply train running on a prototype of the eternal engine that Snowpiercer uses.
>
>  It switched the track and comes in behind Snowpiercer and proceeds to board them, not only does it seem quicker than the Snowpiercer (considering it's the prototype) but also more sophisticated since it hacks their engine in minutes.

My questions is that does this mean that there's 2 separate tracks

> the trains have been running on all this time (7-8 years) or has it simply been running behind them this whole time?
>
> If so what would be the chance they didn't encounter the train in the 7 or so years since departure?

Comment: Spur tracks often run in a small circle off of the main track. It means that the train doesn't even need to reverse or use a turntable.

Comment: IIRC, there are two trains in the original french comics. But the movie, and probably the series, don't follow the comics closely